# Finding minimum and maximum values from range of values

Tags: vba, range, max, minimum

I have an excel with the following data -

```
Value   Date    Time
0   1-May-16    11:20 AM
0   1-May-16    12:05 PM
0   1-May-16    11:30 AM
0   5-May-16    3:40 PM
1   3-May-16    1:00 AM
1   2-May-16    1:45 AM
0   1-May-16    6:04 AM
0   4-May-16    7:09 AM
0   5-May-16    8:20 PM
2   5-May-16    1:53 AM
2   1-May-16    2:54 AM
3   1-May-16    7:35 PM
3   4-May-16    8:34 AM
4   5-May-16    2:12 PM
0   2-May-16    12:11 PM
5   1-May-16    12:45 PM
5   3-May-16    4:55 AM
5   3-May-16    1:12 AM
```

I need to summarize my data by value column with min and max date and time for each value.

The output of the above data should look like this -

```
    Min     Max 
    Date    Time    Date    Time
0   1-May-16    11:20 AM    5-May-16    3:40 PM
1   2-May-16    1:45 AM 3-May-16    1:00 AM
2   1-May-16    2:54 AM 5-May-16    1:53 AM
3   1-May-16    7:35 PM 4-May-16    8:34 AM
4   5-May-16    2:12 PM 5-May-16    2:12 PM
5   3-May-16    1:12 AM 3-May-16    4:55 AM
```

Please help

Comment: Have you tried to use PivotTable? For example: http://www.excel-easy.com/data-analysis/pivot-tables.html

Comment: I have used pivot tables. I wanted to know what VBA code can I use so that I can automate the entire function. The values keep on changing and I do not want to use a pivot table.

Comment: You can use MIN in an array, something like =MIN (($A$1:$A$10=$a1)*($b$1:$b$10))  where a1 is the column in your presenation area

Comment: I need to specifically use VBA as table that I have here is dynamic.. The values keep on changing every minute.. hence an Array will not work.. I need to keep it dynamic so that the dates and times get accurately captured.

Comment: An array would be fine if the values in the sheet change, they will calculate when they change.

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
Set range from which to determine smallest value
Set rng = Sheet1.Range("A1:Z100")

'Worksheet function MIN returns the smallest value in a range 
dblMin = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(rng)
```

From:

http://www.globaliconnect.com/excel/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=105:find-smallest-and-largest-value-in-range-with-vba-excel&catid=79&Itemid=475